# Custom PreferenceActivity layout

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm looking for the best way nowadays to implement a Preference Screen for API 15+.

I have found other solutions including the Android Documentation for one of them:
[PreferenceScreen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html) and [Settings guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

But there is no way to implement a custom layout I've found so far.

[Custom layout is lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821969/custom-preferenceactivity-layout-is-lost-for-nested-preferencescreens)

my code so far:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_activity_settings_nome_usuario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Olááááááá"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/appbarlayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    package com.irriger.cliente.ui.activity;
        public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    /**
     * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
     * to reflect its new value.
     */
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = (preference, value) -> {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(index >= 0 ? listPreference.getEntries()[index] : null);

        } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
            // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
            // using RingtoneManager.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

            } else {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                if (ringtone == null) {
                    // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                    preference.setSummary(null);
                } else {
                    // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                    // name.
                    String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                    preference.setSummary(name);
                }
            }

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    };

    /**
     * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
     * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
     * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
     * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
     * dependent on the type of preference.
     *
     * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
     */
    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            LogUtils.log("(onCreate) ");
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            LogUtils.log("(setupActionBar)");
        }
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
     * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
     */
    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            LogUtils.log("(isXLargeTablet)");
        }
        return (context.getResources()
                .getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration
                .SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            LogUtils.log("(onBuildHeaders)");
        }
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    /**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
     */

    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName) || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(
                fragmentName) || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(
                fragmentName) || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(
                fragmentName) || RegiaoPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceStartFragment(final PreferenceFragment caller, final Preference pref) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            LogUtils.log("(onPreferenceStartFragment) ");
        }
        return super.onPreferenceStartFragment(caller, pref);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(final PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, final Preference preference) {
        super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
        if (preference != null) {
            if (preference instanceof PreferenceScreen) {
                if (((PreferenceScreen) preference).getDialog() != null) {
                    ((PreferenceScreen) preference).getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundDrawable(
                            this.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable());
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows data and sync preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
   }
```

*EDIT* So, what I want to achieve is a screen more or less like this:
[image: Preference Screen]

A good example would be WhatsApp Settings where you have your picture with "preference headers"

Comment: Consider editing the question to specify what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have edited my post... is it more clear now? thanks for the feedback.